# Max available width for text

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

So I have a bunch of `flex div` each containing a number in a `span`. The number can be 2,3,4, up to 7 digits.
I'd like to set each `div`'s `font-size` as big as possible so that the number inside wont overflow. I calculated the div width and divide it by the length of span. but in some small display sizes, the text gets to small. Any ideas?

```js
$('.paramItem').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'font-size': $(this).width() / $(this).html().length / 2
  })
});
```

```css
.paramItem {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paramItem ECG">
  <small>ECG</small>
  <span>85</span>
</div>
<div class="paramItem NIBP">
  <small>ECG</small>
  <span>120/50</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply the result by a determined coefficient. Then see what coefficient can best match what you expect in terms of rendering.

```
'font-size': $(this).width() / $(this).html().length / 2
```

is now

```
'font-size': ($(this).width() / $(this).html().length / 2) * 3 // 3 is the coefficient
```

```js
$('.paramItem').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'font-size': ($(this).width() / $(this).html().length / 2) * 3
  })
});
```

```css
.paramItem {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paramItem ECG">
  <small>ECG</small>
  <span>85</span>
</div>
<div class="paramItem NIBP">
  <small>ECG</small>
  <span>120/50</span>
</div>
```